# Syntax for running batch job from api gateway

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-batch

In my current situation I have been able to create 3 elements:

- A batch queue
- A batch job description
- An API gateway

My goal is to call the "Submit Job" functionality from the API gateway POST action (I'm using a REST Gateway). I have been able to setup the API gateway and it's role in IAM. I found nearly all the settings except for the action or path override. Just using `SubmitJob` provides me with `forbidden` errors. For a lambda function I found the path override I should use by example.

My question:
When calling AWS Batch job to submit a job from the API Gateway, which values should I use in the "Path override" under "Integration request"?

Comment: No one? I only need an example to get me started. The rest I can usually figure out myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AWS, I don't you can associate an API Gateway with a Batch job directly. Instead, you have to set up a lambda function that is triggered by the API Gateway POST data, and this function submit's a job to your AWS batch function.

The steps for doing this are here: [api gateway integration with aws batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158200/api-gateway-integration-with-aws-batch)

And I've done this. One Lambda function can serve for multiple endpoints of your API, and you can use it to route data to batch functions and queue them up.

Comment: Thnx for your answer Marc! I find it odd that you have the option in the API Gateway configuration yet you need lambda in front? Wonder why you are able to just select the "Batch" option from the services if you can't use it. Anyway, I have an example and am able to follow some form of tutorial.

Comment: There are other things you'd want to use an API Gateway for with AWS Batch. I found your answer when I was looking for someone who could explain how I get my batch function to make a HTTPS or FTP file request outside of the AWS VPC. For this, the docs say I need an EGRESS ONLY GATEWAY or NAT or something. Maybe what you saw about about outgoing requests from a function, not incoming requests (Which must be routed to lambdas. Lambdas are "always on" but batch EC2s must spin up each time you add a submit_job() request to its queue.)

Comment: Just wanted to followup on your comment. I am going to use lambda to fix this. However both lambda functions and batch jobs aren't always on. They are both on-demand services which is why I was surprised. Furthermore if you create a new API and POST method, you will be able to directly select Batch as an option when choosing which service to fire. Therefor I had hoped that I could fire off directly.

Comment: I approved this answer as the Lambda function works for me.

Comment: Lambda is more rigid and is designed to be triggered by many inputs, including API requests, but batch is more of a wrapper for running EC2 instances on demand on large functions, but not as an API service.

Comment: I see. Thanks for explaining that.